# Plot3D in Mathematica a function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, graphics, graphics3d

How I plot the attached function $G(t,s)=s(t-1)$ for $0\leq s\leq t\leq1$ and $G(t,s)=t(s-1)$ for $0\leq t\leq s\leq1$(In Picature in Mathematica and How I change the color from yellow).
I have tried the following code

```
T[x_] := T[x] = \[Piecewise] {
{s (1 - t), 0 <= s <= t <= 1},
{t (1 - s), 0 <= t <= s <= 1}}

Plot3D[G[x,t], {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

But cant got the plot.[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load Mathematica code for `G[x,t]`. Or is it `G[s,t]`?

Comment: it is G[t,s]. Please see now

Comment: Try: `Plot3D[T[x], {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
T[s_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{s (1 - t), 0 <= s <= t <= 1}, {t (1 - s), 
    0 <= t <= s <= 1}}]

Plot3D[T[s, t], {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

```
G1 = s (t - 1)
G2 = t (s - 1)
f = Piecewise[{{G1, 0 <= s <= t <= 1}, {G2, 0 <= t <= s <= 1}}]
Plot3D[f, {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 is as follows:**

```
G[t_, s_] := s (t - 1) /; 0 <= s <= t <= 1
G[t_, s_] := t (s - 1) /; 0 <= t <= s <= 1
Plot3D[G[t, s], {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Pastel"]
```

**Option 2 is as follows:**

```
G = {ConditionalExpression[s (t - 1), 0 <= s <= t <= 1], 
   ConditionalExpression[t (s - 1), 0 <= t <= s <= 1]};
Plot3D[G, {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Pastel"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
G[s_, t_] = Min[s, t] (Max[s, t] - 1);
Plot3D[G[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

[image]